# changes in deployment pattern in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013

What are the major changes in deployment pattern in SharePoint 2013 in comparison to SharePoint 2010. One thing I know is that now we have option to deploy either 14 hive or 15 hive at a time. Is there any other changes in deployment?

Answer (score 1):

There haven't been major changes in deployment of SP 2013 farms solutions compared to SP 2010 farm solutions apart from the fact that components need to be deployed to 15 hive instead of 14 hive. Moreover,

> The assemblies in a farm solution in SharePoint 2010 could be deployed
>   with Custom Access Security (CAS) policies. Such policies are ignored
>   in SharePoint 2013; all assemblies in farm solutions in SharePoint
>   2013 run with full trust.Sandboxed solutions with custom code are deprecated in SharePoint 2013. "no code" sandboxed solutions are still viable.
>   The process to install custom site elements and solution packages in SharePoint 2010 Products and SharePoint 2013 has not changed significantly
>   To install solution packages, you can use a new parameter, CompatibilityLevel, to install the solution to the latest version directories, or to use only the current version tracked in the cab file. For more information, see Install-SPSolution.

References: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163902(v=office.15).aspx
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263205(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: At the same time now we have option to deploy either 14 or 15 hive

Comment: Yes if the site is in 2010 mode then deploying to 14 hive makes sense otherwise for 2013 sites deployment needs to be done to 15 hive